# how to invoke detail grid as a click event in the master

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am developing a reusable master detail grid component using backbone and I'm trying to add an event which will load the detail grid when the user clicks on a row in the master grid. I'm unable to determine how a function can be created to achieve this and also how do I pass the arguments to the detail grid's view from a demo page? These arguments should go to the function that loads the detail grid.
A demo page is where I'll create an instance of the component and pass the data model to it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Backbone to better communicate between two components all that you have to do is create a custom js object and have it extend the Backbone.Events(http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

Then define a custom event and a callback to handle the custom event.

```
// A CUSTOM JS OBJECT THAN HANDLES ALL OUR APP'S CUSTOM EVENTS.
var MyAppEventBus = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);

// Options is a Javascript object that contains details required
// load the details data grid.
MyAppEventBus.on("datagrid:showDetailsView",function(options){
    // LOAD THE DATA REQUIRED FOR THE DETAILS GRID.
    // CREATE A DETAILS GIRD VIEW AND PASS THE DATA TO THE DETAILS GRID VIEW INSTANCE.
});
```

In Master Data Grid Component View class, have a listener and a callback defined to listen for events that are triggered to open a details grid.

In that event handler prepare a javascript object that contains data that you think is necessary for the details grid query/display.For instance, you can also pass the id of a container that's created every row where the details grid can be placed for that row in the UI.

Trigger the custom event using your event bus object passing the created javascript object as a parameter.

```
//In the main data grid view have an event listener that handles 
//the click to open child grid view.
events :{
    "click .showDetailGridlnk" : "showDetailsGrid"
},
showDetailsGrid : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // PREPARE THE OPTIONS OBJECT HERE
    var options = {};
    // YOU CAN ALSO SET A DYNAMICALLY GENERATED CONTAINER #ID IN OPTIONS
    // WHICH CAN BE USED TO INSERT THE DETAILS DATA GRID.
    options.el = "<some_dynamic_container_id>";
    MyAppEventBus.trigger("datagrid:showDetailsView",options) 
}
```

Comment: this looks like a good option....thanks for suggesting this. i'll implement it and see how it works.

Comment: i'm just wondering how to get the data required for the details grid from the demo page. how to pass it to the details grid's view

Comment: How do you pass data to your master grid component? Update the code of what you have done till now and where you feel you are struck, so that we can help better.

Comment: By data do you mean the meta information for the gird like column title e.t.c or the actual data for the rows. Also if its data for the rows then why  can't you just do collection.fetch(). You can always get the master id from the row on which you click

Comment: and as i'm new to backbone, i'm not really sure how to use collection.fetch()

Comment: You can add another parameter like  generateGrid( columns ,detailsGridColumns) and capture that in your definition with another property like how you have for columns data. Also change your click event handler callback that shows the details grid to accept this column data as a parameter.

Comment: but the code to Generate the details grid should reside in the component page and not in the demo page. some way is required to just pass the parameters to the click event handler callback. the generateGrid function is creating a grid there itself but it shouldn't create the details grid. the logic for that shouldn't be visible in the demo page

Comment: the click event handler callback function should be the one to crfeate and load the details grid

Comment: One way to do is to define a custom event and a handler for detail grid. In the custom event handler define the details grid like how you have defined for the master grid. And from the master grid pass the id or other data that is required by the details grid as a payload i.e (MyAppEventBus.trigger("datagrid:showDetailsView",options) ) .

Comment: i tried this but it's not working...i've included the code in the description please check it.

Comment: What is happening  when you say its not working? Can you create a fiddle for the above ?

Comment: when i'm clicking on the master grid's row...nothing's happening, the detail grid is not appearing....and i don't know how to create a fiddle...did you read the code? i think the opt hashmap is not getting passed to the callback function...and i don't know hot to make it happen

Comment: Can you post the code for row click event handler on the master grid that handles showing the details grid?

Comment: The trigger call should be as follows:  myAppEventBus.trigger("CustomGrid.selectCell",opt)